# send and HTTPS post to DPD API, not working

Tags: curl

I am trying to post a curl request from my terminal to connect to DPD API using the following command:

`$ sudo curl -H "Content-Type=application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic  RFNNSVRIOk1ZUEFTU1" -H "GEOClient: account/12345" https://api.dpd.co.uk/user/?action=login`

but i keep getting this error

`Cannot GET /esgServer/user/?action=login`

from the documentation, i have this:

```
3.1.1. API Login
URL=POST:/user/?action=login
Every API requires a geoSession except the Login which returns the geoSession which should be 
passed into any further API calls. 
This API sets up a session on the GeoPost servers in whic
h all 
future requests validate against. 
The API requires the username and password base64 encrypting 
and passed across as an Authorization header in the HTTP request, example:
username = DSMITH
password = MYPASSWD
concatenate the username and password wit
h a colon in between and encrypt to base64 as a single 
string:
DSMITH:MYPASSWD
this would result in a string of:
RFNNSVRIOk1ZUEFTU1dE
which can be applied to the http request as a header of:
Authorization: Basic RFNNSVRIOk1ZUEFTU1dE
A returning http respo
nse code of 401 means the username or password are incorrect
Supported HTTP Headers
content
-
type
None
Accept
application/json
Example Request is shown below:
POST /user/?action=login HTTP/1.1
Host: api.dpd.co.uk
Content
-
Type: application/json
Accept: 
application/json
Authorization: Basic RFNNSVRIOk1ZUEFTU1dE
GEOClient: account/123456
Content
-
Length: 0
```

what am i missing?

any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

i forgot to add the -X POST in the command line

so

```
sudo curl -H "Content-Type=application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic  RFNNSVRIOk1ZUEFTU1" -H "GEOClient: account/12345" -X POST https://api.dpd.co.uk/user/?action=login
```